# Get ChangeNotification from not parent-child relationship nor Widget class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have classes like `MainWidget(parent)` -> `ButtonWidget(child)`, `GameManager` and `_KeyChangeNotifier`

MainWidget class returns `ChangeNotifierProvider`

```
return ChangeNotifierProvider<_KeyChangeNotifier>(
  builder: (_) => _KeyChangeNotifier(),
  child:ButtonWidget
```

So,in this case, I can get the `_KeyChangeNotifier` in buttonWidget class. like this.

`Provider.of<_KeyChangeNotifier>(context, listen: false).setStatus(0);`

However now, I want to get the `_KeyChageNotifier` from `GameManager`.

`MainWidget` has the instance of `GameManager`, however `GameManager` is not the widget so it is not under the `ChangeNofitierProvider`.

In this case. Is it possible to get _KeyChangeNotifier from GameManager??

---

Basically my idea was wrong.

SO I made function in `MainWdget` like this

```
setHint(int h){
   Provider.of<_KeyChangeNotifier>(context, listen: false).setHint(h); 
}
```

then call this from GameManager

in GameManager

```
_MainWidgetState parent;
GameManager(p){
   parent = p // parent is passed to GameManager in advance by constructor.
}
function test(){
    this.parent.setHint(2);
}
```

Comment: No, not unless you add a setter and manually set it into the manager. But that's not a good idea. It's hard to tell from your code snippets what a you are trying to achieve. How do GameManager and KeyChangeNotifier relate?

Comment: I see, so my idea is basically wrong. In this case GameManager holds the general variables like (level, score.. etc) and sometimes text should be changed according to level.

Comment: So I made function in `MainWidget` to call `ChangeNotifierProvider` function and call from `GameManager` class.  It works finally.  in  MainWIdget -> `setHint(int h){
    Provider.of<_KeyChangeNotifier>(context, listen: false).setHint(h);
  }` then call it from GameManager `this.parent.setHint(2);`

Answer (score 0):

Your Edit is an improvement but I would not set the `_MainWidgetState` into the `GameManager`. If you think of `GameManager` as some kind of service then it should not know anything about widget states.

You can implement `ChangeNotifier` inside `GameManager` and provide it using `ChangeNotifierProvider<GameManager>` around your `MainWidget`.

```dart
class GameManager with ChangeNotifier {
  int _hint;
  int _status;

  void setHint(int hint) {
    _hint = hint;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int get getHint => _hint;

// same for status or whatever
}
```

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider<GameManager>(
  builder (_) => GameManager(),
  child: MainWidget(),
  //dispose: (_, manager) => manager.dispose(),
)
```

Now you can access the `GameManager` inside of `MainWidget` and `ButtonWidget` and modify its state. And you can listen for it.

There are several ways how to handle state in flutter, especially regarding communication with parent widgets.
I would suggest looking into `Stream` and `Sink` or if you familiar with Rx, you can use [rx_dart's](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) `Observable` and `Subject`.

Other options are [Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc) and [Redux](https://pub.dev/packages/async_redux).